# Why does mcapply cause memory spike and slow execution with renderUI?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, rparallel

I want to parallelize making `plotOutput`s and plots using multiple observers. When I use `lapply` or `mcapply` with `mc.cores = 1` the plots are re-generated quickly, but when `mc.cores` is increased, the first set of plots is created upon the first click of the button and subsequent clicks cause huge memory spikes and failure to update. Why?

```
library(shiny)
library(parallel)
library(ggplot2)

plotsList = list()
plotsReady = reactiveVal(F)
divsReady = reactiveVal(F)

ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(actionButton("goPlot", label = "Make 5 plots")),
  fluidRow(uiOutput("plots")
  )
)

server = function(input, output)
{
  # Make and save plots
  observe({
    plots = mclapply(1:5, function(i)
    {
      ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10)), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
    }, mc.cores = 5)
    plotsList <<- plots
    plotsReady(T)
  }) %>% bindEvent(input$goPlot)
  
  # Make divs
  observe({
    if(plotsReady())
    {
      output$plots = renderUI({
        lapply(1:length(plotsList), function(i)
        {
          plotOutput(paste0("plot", i), height = 100)
        })
      })
      plotsReady(F)
      divsReady(T)
    }
  })
  
  # Render plots
  observe({
    if(divsReady())
    {
      lapply(1:length(plotsList), function(i)
      {
        output[[(paste0("plot", i))]] = renderPlot(plotsList[[i]])
      })
      divsReady(F)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```